# replace a whole sentence with a string in r

Tags: r

I need to replace a whole sentence with a string. For example:

```
# I want to replace "coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)" with "pm10"
species <- c("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","nitrogen dixoide")

# I tried:
sub("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","pm10",species)
gsub("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","pm10",species)
str_replace(species,"coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","pm10")
```

But none of them works. Many thanks for help.

In the real data, the orders are random. That is why I can not use things like

```
species[1] <- "pm10"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with option `fixed = TRUE`

```
> sub("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","pm10",species,fixed = TRUE)
[1] "pm10"             "nitrogen dixoide"

> gsub("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)","pm10",species,fixed = TRUE)
[1] "pm10"             "nitrogen dixoide"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we don't need `sub`

```
species[1] <- "pm10"
```

or use `==`

```
species[species == "coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)"] <- "pm10"
```

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example, in the real data, the orders are random. That is why I can not use the index.

Answer (score 1):

```
species[species == "coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)"] <- "pm10"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `str_replace` you may need `fixed`

```
str_replace(species, fixed("coarse particulate matter (Hourly measured)", ignore_case = TRUE), "pm10")
#[1] "pm10"             "nitrogen dixoide"
```